# Using CSS to move elements opposite of Mouse

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to achieve a CSS mouse effect where:
-if the mouse hovers leftwards on the element, the element moves right.
-if the mouse hovers rightwards on the element, the element moves left.
-if the mouse hovers upwards on the element, the element moves down.
-if the mouse hovers downwards on the element, the element moves up.

What CSS can help me achieve this?

Regards

Comment: This is possible only thru javascript. Check some codepens for inspiration

Comment: CSS cannot track mouse position. For this, you need to supplement it with JavaScript. https://codepen.io/bbenti/pen/zYxGZqE